# Query execution was interrupted sometimes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query,

```
select for_user_id, sum(item_cost) 
from sent_gifts 
where for_user_id NOT IN(1,22,1280881) 
and gift_type NOT IN(2) 
GROUP BY for_user_id 
ORDER BY sum(item_cost) DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

the problem is I sometime get a Query execution was interrupted, not all the time just some times not sure why. most of the time it take 2 tries for it to work. Any Ideas what could be causing that?

Comment: What do you mean by Query execution was interrupted?

Comment: What do you mean by "was interrupted"?  What is interrupting?  How do you know it's being interrupted?

Comment: You cannot get "interrupted", you either return rows successfully or you will receive an error message.